# I want to add "typing" indicator before any message is being sent for bot in Teams using Bot Framework SDK

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, bots, typing

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Welcome"));
```

I want to add "typing" indicator before Welcome is being sent for bot in Teams.
Using BotFramework.

However, every message my bot is sending has no "typing" before and it just appears after a few seconds.

How do I do it in C#?

Comment: Are you using the TypingIndicator middleware ?

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@GiangNguyen's answer is a partial answer; you should use [ShowTypingMiddleware](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/b0b91668f69ba2c45c17b0aa5d00a3cb86b70bfb/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs) if you want to send typing activities before *every* message. I say it's only a partial answer because I don't believe this will actually work for welcome messages.

---

First, a quick note about Welcome Messages on the Teams channel. They are a huge pain to test. Teams ties user interactions with a bot to the bot's `appId`, so a user can only ever get a welcome message from a bot once--it doesn't matter if they hide or delete the conversation or the bot--they will only ever get the welcome message *once*. To get around this for the sake of testing, you have a couple of options:

1. Create a new App Registration every time you want to test this (because it will generate a new AppId), or
2. Put some logic in `OnMessageAsync` that calls the same code you use in `OnMembersAddedAsync()`. For example, if you type "test welcome message", it will call the same code you use in `OnMembersAddedAsync()` (`...if (turnContext.Activity.Text === "test welcome message"...`), like sending your actual welcome message. Use this for testing and then you can remove for production. I recommend this approach.

---

So, the reason there won't be a typing activity for a welcome message when using ShowTypingMiddleware is because the middleware only fires when the bot receives a message, which typically doesn't happen for welcome messages. Instead, you need to send the typing activity manually:

```
var typing = new Activity() { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing };
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(typing);
```

---

That being said, some channels/clients struggle with the ShowTypingMiddleware. If you're looking for help troubleshooting and this answer doesn't apply, let me know what channel/client you're using and what code you're using to send the typing indicator and I'll see if I can still help.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Startup.cs

```
 services.AddSingleton<ShowTypingMiddleware>();
```

Then your AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs

```
public AdapterWithErrorHandler(ShowTypingMiddleware showTypingMiddleware)
            : base(configuration, logger)
{
...
Use(showTypingMiddleware);
...
}
```